# Calculating the area of a circle

Tags: c++, interview-questions

This is one of tasks, which I had to do for the recruitment process at some company. Unfortunately they didn't like it so I've decided to share it here for discussion.

CircleArea.h

```
#ifndef CIRCLEAREA_H_
#define CIRCLEAREA_H_

//PI Number, with max precision for double (8 bytes)
const double PI = 3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875;

double circleArea(double radius);

#endif
```

CircleArea.cpp

```
#include "CircleArea.h"
#include <stdexcept>

double circleArea(double radius)
{
    if(radius < 0)
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Radius cannot be less than zero");
    }

    return PI * radius * radius;
}
```

Why could the solution have been disliked by the recruiters?

Comment: Were you required to use separate files?

Comment: No, there wasn't any requirements for that. I've just prepared a project with a few files (also for other tasks) and a makefile to compile all of them easily.

Comment: The constant is only accurate up to 3.141592653589793 and maybe there is a lack of comments, but I don't really think that would be an issue in such a small task. Can you elaborate as to why they didn't like it?

Comment: If you have the original problem statement and any other problems they gave you relevant to this one, it would be helpful to include that to see what they were looking for.  If you were given a few problems that revolved around calculating area of shapes, perhaps they were looking for OO-based solutions.

Comment: Perhaps you should have put some unit tests and cover edge cases.

Comment: Did they specifically not like your answer to this question or did they not like your answers overall to your multiple interview questions?

Comment: Whatever you have done here is functional programming. They might have expected you to do it using OOPs. I mean, with class and functions as the interview is for C++. The program has nothing to do with C++.

Comment: Personally I don't like that the constant `PI` is stored in the .h file (regardless of how it is defined/calculated).  Now any file that includes circlearea.h gets a definition of `PI` for no reason.

Comment: @mentat: I did.

Comment: @JS1: They just didn't accept my candidacy. I don't know what was the main reason - probably not this task, but I wanted to have the others' opinion. And - in fact - got a few good remarks.

Comment: @Raams: It wasn't specified. There was just a simple command: write a function calculating circle area. Language is of your choice. The same for other tasks.

Comment: @twohundredping: Yes. Usually I do it like this. However at the beginning I was wondering about a class and a static variable for PI, but decided to do it in C and then forgot to move it to .cpp file. Thanks for this comment.

Answer (score 11):

I assume one of the complaints was with the constant.  There are various ways to calculate pi, using an exact calculation rather than using some number of digits.

Here's one example (in C++14):

```
constexpr auto pi()
{
    return std::acos(-1);
}
```

(For C++11, use a non-`auto` type, such as `double` or `float`.)

The [`constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) keyword will allow this to be calculated at compile time.  You could still assign the return value to a constant or call the function inline where needed.  If you *don't* have C++11, then you can use `const` in place of `constexpr`, and just assign it to a constant.

Comment: @Sean: Another one might be with the exception-handling, but I'm not too sure of a better alternative.  But you were still right to account for such an argument.

Comment: I actually had to use C++14 for this piece of code to work. It was because function's return type is auto. I'm not sure, if I had done something wrong.

Comment: @fsacer: Oh yeah, I forgot to mention that returning `auto` is C++14.  You're right.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the various comments, and your other recent questions with the same context (recruiters didn't like the solution), it seems the problem in this question was just a very small piece of the bigger picture. I'm pretty sure the main reason of the rejection lies elsewhere, not in this simple piece of code.

In addition to @Jamal's answer about the value of PI,
the remark by [@twohundredping](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/66571/twohundredping) in a comment is also noteworthy.
The requirement concerns the calculation of the square of a circle,
and doesn't say anything about \$\pi\$.
Although it's an obvious detail,
the use of \$\pi\$ is still an implementation detail,
and therefore it doesn't belong in the header file,
it should be in the `.cpp` file of the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Name space crowding?

```
const double PI = 3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875;
```

Much like coveted 1 and 2-letters URLs, creating a constant named `PI` can easily collide with other code.  Further, `PI` looks like a `#define` for my tastes.

```
#include <cmath>
double circleArea(double radius) {
  static const double pi = std::acos(-1); // Or some variation 
  return pi * radius * radius;
}
```

---

BTW OP's `PI * radius * radius` has a small advantage over `radius * radius * PI` as `radius * radius` may underflow  for values just less than `sqrt(DBL_TRUE_MIN)`, but not `PI * radius * radius`

Answer (score 1):

Two items in the original code can be improved:

1. Use the predefined constant `M_PI` in math.h.
2. There is no special need to check for radius < 0 because (-r * -r) == (r * r).

Comment: i cant agree with the second point, the area of a circle with radius less than zero is not defined, so silently responding as though it is OK is wrong

Comment: `M_PI` is not in standard C nor C++.  Various implementations do define it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that an important problem is that you didn't check for overflow and underflow of the parameter, that would produce errors at run time.

See, for instance, the first answer to this question: [How to detect double precision floating point overflow and underflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655070/how-to-detect-double-precision-floating-point-overflow-and-underflow)